# Appcelerator Titanium 3 Android emulator environment errors

Tags: android, node.js, titanium, appcelerator

I am a new user of Appcelerator Titanium (installed on Windows(X86)). I tried to test my development environment (Titanium SDK + Android SDK + Node.js), but I'm getting some errors:

```
Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Program Files\Fichiers communs'

[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8
```

The trace:

```
 C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\longjohn\dist\longjohn.js:184
    throw e;       
 Error: EPERM, operation not permitted 'C:\Program Files\Fichiers communs'
at fs.readdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
at scan (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\emulators\genymotion.js:138:25)
at scan (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\emulators\genymotion.js:150:26)
at C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\emulators\genymotion.js:156:10
at C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\emulators\genymotion.js:113:8
at q.process (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:728:21)
at processImmediate (timers.js:330:15)
at C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:693:21
at Array.forEach (native)
at _each (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:32:24)
at _insert (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:678:11)
at q.push (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:705:15)
at C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\emulators\genymotion.js:129:12
at queue.drain (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\node-appc\lib\subprocess.js:108:3)
at next (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:723:31)

at C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:693:21
at Array.forEach (native)
at _each (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:32:24)
at _insert (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:678:11)
at q.push (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:705:15)
at Object.findExecutable (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\node-appc\lib\subprocess.js:113:8)
at async.parallel.virtualbox (C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\emulators\genymotion.js:99:20)
at C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:521:25
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am working on ubuntu 12.04 and I was having the same problem,
just be sure that your user has (read - write - execute ) permissions on 'C:\Program Files\Fichiers communs'

this solutions worked for me.

Comment: My user have all permissions needed on 'C:\Program Files\Common Files' (there is no folder having the name 'Fichiers communs') !

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you have resolved your problem today but just like you I used to have this problem with Titanium Studio and after a lot of time spent one thing resolved all problems I had with TS : I just deleted the genymotion.js file which is located for you at

```
C:\Users\coyote\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.0.GA\node_modules\titanium-sdk\lib\emulators\genymotion.js
```

I hope that will help you if you always have such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is about permission on the folder 'C:\Program Files\Fichiers communs'. You may see it as  Accessories or Common Files. Take ownership and give modify permissions. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Over the folder `"Common files"/"Fichiers communs"/"Archivos comunes"`. (the name depends on your language), press right-button of your mouse.

`Properties --> Tab "Security" --> Avanced options --> Tab "Owner" :`
Press Edit and change the owner from (in my case "SYSTEM") to your username.

Applies the changes.

That solved my problem.

Edit: this solution is only for windows users.

Answer (score 0):

for windows user
http://nodejs.org/download/

Windows Installer (.msi)